# How to pass value to a global variable through a Button command in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, button, arguments

I'm a newbie to python. Would you be able to help me find a way to pass a value onto the CommonPage class for the 'mypage' variable, rather than it being hardcoded onto there. I plan for both pages A and B to have the same format and structure, but different values for variables (such as the title as in this example). This is why I would like to use only one class for both pages A and B, rather than two separate classes with similar code but different values for the variables. Is this possible?

thank you! any help would be much appreciated

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

class MyApp(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        Tk.__init__(self)
        container = ttk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        self.frames = {}
        for F in (HomePage, CommonPage):
            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='NSEW')
        self.show_frame(HomePage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()

class HomePage(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        self.controller = controller
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        # create all of the main containers
        top_frame = Frame(self, bg='blue', width=355, height=50)
        mid_frame = Frame(self, bg='MediumPurple4', width=350, height=50)
        bottom_frame = Frame(self, bg='#a0ccda', width=350, height=100)

        # to go inside top_frame
        titleLabel = Label(top_frame, font=('Arial', 23, 'bold'), text="My App",
                           bd=5, fg='snow',bg='blue', width=19, height=1)
        titleLabel.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=N)
        top_frame.pack()

        # to go inside mid_frame
        titleLabel = Label(mid_frame, font=('Helvetica', 15, 'italic'), text="",
                           bd=5, fg='snow',bg='black', width=30, height=1)
        titleLabel.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=N)
        mid_frame.pack()

        # to go inside bottom_frame
        titleLabel = Label(bottom_frame, font=('Helvetica', 15, 'italic'), text="Select Button Page Below", bd=5, fg='snow',bg='gray', width=30)
        titleLabel.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=N)
        # button to CommonPage
        # need to pass the Page Button selected to the CommonPage class 
        btnPageA = Button(bottom_frame, text="Page A", font="Arial 20",
                          command=lambda: [self.controller.show_frame(CommonPage)], 
                          bg="#a0ccda", width=22)
        btnPageA.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W)
        btnPageB = Button(bottom_frame, text="Page B", font="Arial 20",
                          command=lambda: [self.controller.show_frame(CommonPage)],
                          bg="#a0ccda", width=22)
        btnPageB.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=W)
        bottom_frame.pack()

class CommonPage(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        self.controller = controller  
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
  
        top_frame = Frame(self, bg='blue', width=355, height=50)
        bottom_frame = Frame(self, bg='#a0ccda', width=350, height=0)
        btnHomePage = ttk.Button(top_frame, text='Home Page',
                                 command=lambda: self.controller.show_frame(HomePage))
        btnHomePage.grid(row=0, sticky=W)
        ## hardcoded as shown, this needs to be passed when a page button is selected
        SelectedPage = "Page B"  
        if SelectedPage == "Page A":
            mypage = "Page A"
        else: 
            mypage = "Page B"
        ##
        
        titleLabel = Label(top_frame, font=('Arial', 23, 'bold'), text=mypage, bd=5, fg='snow',bg='blue', width=19, height=1)
        titleLabel.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=S)
        top_frame.pack()
        bottom_frame.pack()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = MyApp()
    app.title('Mobile App')
    app.geometry('{}x{}'.format(355, 230))
```

Comment: please provide a [mre], also yes kinda possible but depends on how similar the pages are, if only literally the data changes (not data labels and that stuff) then very easy yes, otherwise you probably want to make one class that will have all the basics that the two pages share and are the same and then create two more classes that will be pageA and pageB that will inherit from the base page

Comment: Don't just stick the word "python" in your question to make it not a duplicate. If it's not somehow, incorporate that in the title and explain why that's so in the body.